# Using a custom star type with a Gmail filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have set up a Gmail filter that marks all incoming mail from a certain mailing list with a star. Right now, the filter automatically applies the standard yellow star. How can I set it to use the blue star instead?

Comment: It doesn't look possible. The Filter tool only gives an option to add a star, not which star to use.

Comment: Heh, if it had been as easy as using a dropdown in the filter setup menu, I wouldn't have had to ask. I was hoping there was an advanced setting somewhere that I had missed, but I'm not holding out much hope.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Maybe when the extra stars graduate out of the Labs.

Comment: If only! The extra stars (AKA "Superstars") [graduated back in May](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/3-labs-graduations-1-retirement.html). At least looking up that blog post reminded me to check out nested labels, so I got _something_ out of this question.

Comment: Ugh. You're right. I'm behind the times.

Comment: That's correct, we currently do not have the functionality to allow you to use different kinds of stars with filters.

Comment: One workaround is to assign labels, but name the labels with emojis. For example, "★" it's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sorry, we do not currently have functionality that allows you to use different kinds of stars with filters.

Comment: Accepted because the OP is [the Community Manager for Gmail](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/user?userid=00709599094295275315&hl=en).

Comment: Is this *ever* going to happen? Presumably if people use more than one type of star in the first place, they may want more than one type of star applied to messages via filter...

Comment: Been years now...is there any chance of being able to apply superstars with a filter?  Or use superstars in the iPhone app?  Superstars are so useful and makes my workflow so much easier - why are they "second class citizens" with respect to almost all other gmail functionality?

Comment: Add two more years and still no joy. It's now end of 2019 and it's still the case that only the default yellow star can be added by filters. I'd be inclined to file this alongside Google Sheets' _Cannot enter spaces in right-justified text_ bug, in the _All Hope Abandon, Bugs/FeatureReqs That Enter Here_ category.

Answer (score 11):

All of the superstars are supported and have been for quite a while:

- has:yellow-star - Messages with a yellow star.
- has:red-bang - Messages with a red exclamation mark.
- has:yellow-bang - Messages with a yellow exclamation mark.
- has:purple-question - Messages with a purple question mark.
- has:orange-guillemet - Messages with two orange forward arrows.
- has:blue-info - Messages with a blue i.
- has:red-star - Messages with a red star.
- has:orange-star - Messages with an orange star.
- has:green-star - Messages with a green star.
- has:blue-star - Messages with a blue star.
- has:purple-star - Messages with a purple star.

For what it's worth, I tried a complex search using the blue-info and it did not work properly, but when I switched to a red-bang it did work.  I don't know how well it works... I wanted to perform a search for items from a certain sender that were not starred, and it definitely didn't work for the blue-info!

But... for basic and compound searches, this should work extremely well!

Comment: I actually briefly accepted this answer before I realized you answered the wrong question. You're right that you can use this syntax to search for questions, but you can't use it for setting up filters. The filter menu -- which has changed since I originally asked this question -- still only gives a single "Star it" checkbox, not a dropdown menu or anything like that.